real time anormal detection from surveillance footages
I'm implementing a model for real time anomaly detection from surveillance videos. so I need to notify the user when running the model if anomaly is detected. the model is trained for normal videos within 5 days day time. input is videos and output is anormal frames at real time. how can I proceed to feed video data and output take anormal frames
